# Box Description: How to do?

Tags: php, css

How do I make a box description? I'll explain, through a small snippet in PHP I have created an algorithm that provides name end the ellipsis to indicate that it is not finished ... I would like that when I pass the mouse over the dots appear a small box for indicate the entire name. How do? Have you any source as to pass? many Thanks and sorry for my English...

This It's the source code php

```
if(strlen($category['name']) >= 13) {
    echo substr($category['name'], 0, 13) . "...";
} else { 
echo $category['name']; 
}
```

EDIT: the box should appear during hover css event

Comment: Can you describe, what and when you want to see in browser window? Can't really understand the question.

Comment: instead of trimming the data why dont you use css to do a `text-overflow: ellipse;` It's pretty [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/text-overflow)

Answer (score 0):

I think You should do somethink like this:

```
<?php
// ...
echo '<h3' . (strlen($category['name']) > 13 ? ' title="'.$category['name'].'" : '') . '>' . (strlen($category['name']) > 13 ? substr($category['name'], 0, 13) . '&hellip;' : $category['name']) . '</h3>';
// ...
?>
```

You need to use the tag attribute `title` and fill it with some value to show like a *hint box*...

Also You could use only a CSS setting `text-overflow: ellipse;` that will add the `&hellip;` entity and trim the text after it is wider than the area it is displayed in...